# How to get script elemnt in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the url under the script's in beautifulsoup4 in python. Lets assume we have a js code like that

```
<script>
  var data = [{
      tag: "A",
      name: "shelf",
      url: "/book"
    },
    {
      tag: "A",
      name: "publisher",
      url: "/computer"
    }, {
      tag: "A",
      name: "book",
      url: "/calculator"
    }, {

</script>
```

how can i take the url with using bs4

```
for i in soup.find_all('script'):
    print(i.get('url'))
```

i have tried so far this code but it didnt work

Comment: Get the content of the script tag, find the lines that contain `url:`, find the last word on those lines.

Comment: How do we get content of the script tag ?

Comment: In your loop above, I believe you can use `i.text` to get the text of the script.  (`i.get('url')` didn't work because url is not a direct attribute of the script tag.)

Comment: Sadly it did not work

Comment: The page probably has lots of script tags that don't have any text, e.g. `<script src="URL"></script>`. You need to skip over those until you get to the one with inline code.

Comment: You can iterate through the data in a for loop. Something like: for key, value in json_data. If the key equals say 'url' then you can grab the link that way.